# Sizing down MatIcon looks fuzzy vs. sizing down SVG looks perfect

Tags: css, angular, svg, angular-material

Material icons are easy to use and usually look great. However I now need to size them down:

```html
<div class="status-icon">
  <mat-icon>
    remove_circle_outline
  </mat-icon>
</div>
```

```css
.status-icon {
 .material-icons {
    font-size: 16px !important;
 }
}
```

Well, it works, but the result looks a bit fuzzy. The lines are far from beeing sharp.

So I downloaded the original [SVG](https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=remove_circle_outline&style=baseline) and added it directly:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" height="16" width="16">
  <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
  <path d="M7 11v2h10v-2H7zm5-9C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8z"/>
</svg>
```

And it looks perfectly. No matter how small or big the SVG is scaled it looks great.

I thought MatIcon is using SVGs as well. If not, what image format is it using? And is there an easy way to tell MatIcon to use the SVG format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular material icons are using font icons, so while they are scalable, they can still have aliasing issues as you are probably seeing.

The SVGs are not built into the standard mat-icon, but you can register your own svg icons and use them the same way.

Once registered, you would render an svg icon like this:

```html
<mat-icon svgIcon="thumbs-up"></mat-icon>
```

TS:

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {MatIconRegistry} from '@angular/material/icon';

/**
 * @title SVG icons
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'icon-svg-example',
  templateUrl: 'icon-svg-example.html',
})
export class IconSvgExample {
  constructor(iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
        'thumbs-up',
        sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/img/examples/thumbup-icon.svg'));
  }
}
```

https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview